# How can I make a pyqt5 application detect keyPressEvents even when the application is not focussed in windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyqt5

I am making an application that will change a mdiArea's colour dependant on whether the "O" or "P" key is pressed. This is so when using a mod in assetto corsa I can track whether my DRS is on as there isnt a ui element in the mod I am using. The program tracks the inputs as I'd like it to when I have clicked in the window (ie it is focussed) however I need it to run even when I am "focussed" on the game when playing with borderless windows.

```
class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
        uic.loadUi('drs.ui', self) # Load the .ui file
        self.show() # Show the GUI
        self.drs = False
        

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_O:
            if self.drs == True:
                self.drs = False
                self.label_2.setText("OFF")
                self.mdiArea.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("red")))
            else:
                self.drs = True
                self.label_2.setText("ON")
                self.mdiArea.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("green")))
        if e.key()==Qt.Key_P:
            self.drs = False
            self.label_2.setText("OFF")
            self.mdiArea.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("red")))
```

I have tried using the keyboard module but I can't seem to integrate those events with pyqt without using a while True: loop which obviously stop pyqt from reaching its event loop which stops widgets from updating(I did try using signals and another thread but could not get this to work either). I have also tried applications that "pin" the window on top and this doesnt work either as despite not being hidden they are not technically in focus

Basically how can I make the application detect keyboard events regardless of window focus

Comment: Set up a low-level keyboard hook.

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that with pyqt, do you know if its possible to use the keyboard module's events with pyqt. Because assigning it to a variable in a loop doesnt work as I said in my question